# How can I specifically target and apply a function to individual images from a GET requested JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

My question has two parts here: I have created an Instagram clone and would like to be able to click on each individual image and have a like feature. The way that I currently have this set up is by clicking on an image, it would just change the color of the `fa-heart` class from grey to red. This works fine, but I would like to target each `img` / `<div>` individually. I am pulling all of my images in via a JSON file, the problem is when clicking on one photo all of the hearts change. How can I specifically target each item individually with this functionality?

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/tecaha/edit?output

And here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="top">     

        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li id="logo">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SmdPZ6T.png" />
          </li>
          <li id="profile-photo">
            <img src="https://scontent-sea1-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/10731946_1517235648523785_1216221661_a.jpg" />
            <p class="username">username</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
      <main>
        <div id="feed-container">
            <ul id="images">

            </ul>
          </div>
          <ul class="comment-list">

          </ul>
      </main>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-family: "proxima-nova", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #3E6D93;
  height: 50px;
}
.top {
  background: #467ea6;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0.01, #467ea6), to(#27608c));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#467ea6', endColorstr='#27608c', GradientType=0);
  width: 100%;
}
.top li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#home-button, .fa-home {
  float: left;
  background-color: #305F87;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 35px;
}
.fa-home {
  padding-left: 12px;
}
#logo img {
  float: right;
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding: 6px;
}
#profile-photo  {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #305F87;
  border-right: 1px solid #305F87;
  width: auto;
}
#profile-photo img  {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#profile-photo p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;

}
#feed-container {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  width: 650px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#images img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
}
.below-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.like {
  float: left;
}
.fa-heart {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.liked {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.image-info {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 437px;
  height: 52px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.image-info p {
  color: #467ea6;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.more {
  float: right;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
.more, .info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
#clear {
  clear: both;
}
.comment-container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#add-a-comment {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 550px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#add-a-comment p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#add-a-comment input[type=text] {
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
}
input, select, textarea{
  color: #f00;
}
.inserted {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*#addNewComment {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  width: 100px;
}*/
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
// Variable of html strings
var bottom = '<div class="below-image">' +
    '<div class="like">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="image-info">' +
    '<p>User Info</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="more">' +
    '<button class="info">···</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div id="clear"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div id="add-a-comment">' +
    '<div class="comment-container">' +
    '<form class="comment" action="index.html" method="post">' +
    '<input id="enter" type="text" name="newcomment" value="" placeholder="Add a comment...">' +
    '</form>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>';


// GET Request to grab the data from the JSON file
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonURL = "https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json";
    $.getJSON(jsonURL, function (json) {
        var imgList = "";
    //var newImage = "http://yourbizrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Staying-Motivated.jpg";

    $.each(json, function (i) {
            imgList += '<li><img class="inserted" src= " ' + json[i] + ' ">' + bottom;
        });
        $('#images').append(imgList);
    });
});

// Like Photos

// $(document).ready(function() {
//   $(".inserted").on('click', '.inserted', function() {
//     $(".fa-heart").toggleClass(".liked");
//   });
// });


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#images').dblclick(function() {
    $('.fa-heart').addClass('liked');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the image and below-image blocks in a div with class 'post'. Then you can apply a class to the specific 'post' div for every post that is liked. For example:

```
<div class="post">
  <img class="inserted.../>
  <div class="below-image">...</div>
</div>
```

Now you can respond to a double click of the image by setting

```
$(document).on('dblclick', 'img.inserted', function(){
  var post_block = $(this).parents('.post').first();
  post_block.addClass('post-liked');

});
```

This will add the **post-liked** class to the containing block. Now you css can respond appropriately by showing the correct heart.

```
.post-liked .fa-heart {
   color: #f00;
}
```

When loading from your backend, you only need to add the class post-liked in your javascript to the specific posts that need to have the red heart.

Comment: Phil, Thank you! This seems like it will work. My only question/ confusion lies here: Since I am inserting the `<li><img class="inserted" src= " ' + json[i] + ' ">' + bottom;` when the `$.each` function is called, would I wrap the `<div class="post">` in that? If not maybe can you show me an updated version of the bin to show me exactly what you are talking about?

Comment: Hmmm.. I tried that and it does not work. See here : http://jsbin.com/tecaha/edit?output

Comment: I updated the dlbclick handler a little in the post above, so it will respond better wherever it is placed in your code. Also, I would move the <div class="post"> tags inside the <li> tags you have. See if that works